# Binary search tree lazy deletion

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, lazy-evaluation

I want to implement a lazy deletion into my code. I have added a boolean value to keep track of when a node is "deleted"/marked deleted. I am unsure of what methods to actually change. Here are my remove and insert methods. I attempted the remove, but not the insert. I know for sure that the insert method will have to do a lot of checking. Please advise.

```
template<class Comparable>
bool search_tree<Comparable>::remove(treeNode<Comparable> * &root,
        const Comparable &x) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return false;

    if (x < root->data)
        return remove(root->lftChild, x);
    if (root->data < x)
        return remove(root->rtChild, x);

    root->deleted = true;
    return true;
}

template<class Comparable>
bool search_tree<Comparable>::insert(treeNode<Comparable> * &root,
        const Comparable &x) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new treeNode<Comparable>(x, NULL, NULL);
        return true;
    } else if (x < root->data)
        return insert(root->lftChild, x);
    else if (root->data < x)
        return insert(root->rtChild, x);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert function should work as is unless x is equal to an item that has been deleted then it wont get inserted. If x is equal to root->data you need to make sure deleted is false.

And your remove function looks like it should work fine.